# Classloading a plugin for a custom application produces a NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, plugins, abstract-class, extend, urlclassloader

I'm having some issues wrapping my head around the concept of classloading, I've been programming for a little while now but I'm relatively knew to how classloading works, I've gone through a couple of examples and read about the details behind classloading and classes themselves, while I understand it to a certain extent theres a concept thats escaping me and seems rather hard to put into search-friendly terms.

Essentially, I'm trying to create 'guilds' for a gamemode I've been developing for Minecraft, these guilds lie in their own classes and are loaded up with the game at startup or whenever the method 'reloadGuildFiles()' is issued. I develop these classes by first exporting the main application and adding it to the classpath of the guild being created as well as the main applications dependencies.

**Here is the 'reloadGuildFiles' method.**

```
public void reloadGuildFiles() {
  unloadGuildFiles();

  synchronized ( _sync ) {
   System.out.println( "Loading guild class files." );

   File guildDataSourceDirectory = new File( "Prospect/Guilds/" );

   URLClassLoader urlcl = null;

   try {
    urlcl = URLClassLoader.newInstance( new URL[] { guildDataSourceDirectory.toURI().toURL() }, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() );
   } catch ( Exception e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
   }

   if ( urlcl == null )
    return;

   for ( File guildDataFile : guildDataSourceDirectory.listFiles() ) {
    if ( !guildDataFile.getName().endsWith( ".class" ) ) {
     System.out.println( "Skipping " + guildDataFile.getName() );
     continue;
    }

    try {
     String className = guildDataFile.getName().substring( 0, guildDataFile.getName().lastIndexOf( "." ) );

     System.out.println( "Loading: " + className + "\n" +
       "\tfrom: " + guildDataFile.getPath() );

     Class<?> clazz = urlcl.loadClass( className );

     Object object = clazz.newInstance();

     if ( object instanceof Guild == false ) {
      System.out.println( "Object loaded is not an instance of Guild." );
      continue;
     }

     Guild guild = ( Guild ) object;

     if ( _guildMap.containsKey( guild.getName() ) ) {
      System.out.println( "Duplicate guild names in guild map: " + guild.getName() );
      continue;
     }

     _guildMap.put( guild.getName(), guild );
     guild.onGuildLoaded();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
     System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
     e.printStackTrace();
     continue;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

**Here is the Guild class contained within the main application.**

```
public abstract class Guild {
 public abstract String getName();

 public void onGuildLoaded() {
  System.out.println( "Loaded: " + getName() );
 }
}
```

**Here is the class I am trying to classload**

```
public class Warrior extends Guild {
 public String getName() {
  returns "Warrior";
 }
}
```

**Here is the error it is giving me:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Guild
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at GuildManager.reloadGuildFiles(GuildManager.java:53)
        at Prospect.enable(Prospect.java:64)
        at PluginLoader.load(PluginLoader.java:205)
        at PluginLoader.reloadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:189)
        at je.d(je.java:1196)
        at je.a(je.java:430)
        at bg.a(SourceFile:24)
        at bh.a(SourceFile:218)
        at je.a(je.java:56)
        at dp.a(SourceFile:85)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.h(SourceFile:267)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:208)
        at bw.run(SourceFile:482)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Guild
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 25 more
```

From what I can gather and from what I understand, even though the main application is on the build path of the class to be loaded, the classloader does not recognize the class Guild. I think I need to try and make the classloader recognize the Guild class contained in the main application, is there anyway to do this or is there something I am clearly doing wrong?

Comment: Is 'Guild' your own class or a MineCraft class? If it's yours, try adding in a default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible problem I can see here is that `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` for some reason produces a classloader that can't be used to access `Guild` class.

Try this instead:

```
urlcl = URLClassLoader.newInstance( new URL[] { guildDataSourceDirectory.toURI().toURL() }, Guild.class.getClassLoader());
```